# Tomcat Save Log History

Tags: java, tomcat, logging

I am using log4j in webapp deployed on tomcat, but cuurently my logs comes under catalina.log file, but only error logs remain in history, i want my all logs to be remain in history , additionally it will be good if if i get logs datewise.

my logs4j looks like this

```
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, myConsoleAppender


log4j.appender.myConsoleAppender=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.myConsoleAppender.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.myConsoleAppender.layout.ConversionPattern= [%t] %d{dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss,SSS} : %c %x : %m%n
```

i am only using info level of logs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
# Define the root logger with appender file 
log4j.rootLogger = DEBUG, FILE

# Pattern to output the caller's file name and line number.
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%-5p : %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %c{1}:%L - %m%n

# Define the daily rolling file appender
log4j.appender.FILE=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.FILE.File=/logs/app.log
log4j.appender.FILE.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MMM-dd

# Define the layout for the file appender
log4j.appender.FILE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.FILE.layout.ConversionPattern= %-5p : %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

Above will create a log file  on the tomcat installation directory under the folder `logs`on daily basis. You can change the log file path by modifying the `log4j.appender.FILE.File=/path/to/logfile`

Comment: Thnx Shiva. I will try it