# log4j appender issue - unable to print debug, error levels

Tags: java, log4j

I am using a log4j for logging.

This is how my log4j.properties looks like

```
# Root logger option
log4j.rootLogger=info, debug, error file


# Direct log messages to a log file
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender


#Redirect to Tomcat logs folder
#log4j.appender.file.File=${catalina.home}/logs/logging.log

log4j.appender.file.File=C:\\Users\\raj_sanpui\\Desktop\\Automation\\test.log
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=10MB
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

Each of my Java files constructor has this call:

```
public class IMGOperations {

    private org.apache.log4j.Logger log;
    private String hostname;
    private String sysid;
    private String dicomfilepath;

    public IMGOperations(String hostname, String sysid, String dicomfilepath)
    {
        this.hostname=hostname;
        this.sysid=sysid;
        this.dicomfilepath=dicomfilepath;

        PropertyConfigurator.configure(mainConfig.LOG4JCONFPATH);
        log = Logger.getLogger(mainConfig.class);
    }
```

I am getting this error on running my Java program:

```
log4j:ERROR Could not find value for key log4j.appender.debug
log4j:ERROR Could not instantiate appender named "debug".
log4j:ERROR Could not find value for key log4j.appender.error file
log4j:ERROR Could not instantiate appender named "error file".
log4j:ERROR Could not find value for key log4j.appender.debug
```

I am basically a C/C++ folk, who knows Core Java, and pretty much a noob in this stuff. So please pardon me, if you find it too basic.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is in your second line, it should be:

```
# Root logger option
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, stdout, file
```

This means you will log at INFO level, and instantiate log4j appenders for stdout and files.  Needless to say, INFO can be switched for any other logging level (TRACE, DEBUG, INFO, WARN, ERROR, FATAL).

**EDIT:**

The log4j.rootLogger takes 2 or more arguments.  The first argument, is the logging level, and any following are the names of log4j appenders.  You are seeing the error you have presented in your question because there are no appenders by the names of "debug" or "error file", as described by the line:

```
log4j:ERROR Could not find value for key log4j.appender.debug
log4j:ERROR Could not find value for key log4j.appender.error file
```

**EDIT 2:**

Given the below config file:

```
# Root logger option
log4j.rootLogger=info, debug, error file


# Direct log messages to a log file
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender


#Redirect to Tomcat logs folder
#log4j.appender.file.File=${catalina.home}/logs/logging.log

log4j.appender.file.File=C:\\Users\\raj_sanpui\\Desktop\\Automation\\test.log
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=10MB
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

Log4j expects appenders to be defined for "debug" and "error file", however, you have only defined an appender for "file".  You have defined your appender like so:

```
log4j.rootLogger=info, file
 log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
```

To use an appender named "debug", you would need another similar line:

```
log4j.rootLogger=info, debug
log4j.appender.debug=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
```

There should be a one to one mapping between the appenders you declare in the log4j.rootLogger property, and your appender definitions.

It might help if you think of each of the properties like this:

```
log4j.appender.file => create new file appender object
log4j.appender.file.File => set the file property of the file appender
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize => set the max file size of the file appender
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex => set the max backup index property of the file appender
log4j.appender.file.layout => set the layout of the file appender
etc...
```

Comment: I am getting same error, even if i use `log4j.rootLogger=INFO, stdout, file` and everything else is same in conf file. Sorry, did i miss anything?

Comment: Im sorry, but you are not getting the same error.  My answer should fix the problem you originally presented, now you have another problem.  If you can provide me with more information, i.e. the exact error message, I might be able to help you further.

Comment: `log4j:ERROR Could not find value for key log4j.appender.stdout file`
`log4j:ERROR Could not instantiate appender named "stdout file".` These are the errors i am still facing. My class name are IMGOperations.java and HL7Outbound.java One more error is: `log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (com.dell.dcca.hl7.quantum.automation.HL7Outbound).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.`

Comment: apologies, get rid of stdout - you have a rolling file appender defined for file, but nothing for stdout, in your config.  You would add in a console appender if you wanted to use that.

Comment: What is the solution then? If i get rid of stdout, i am in the original log4j.properties. What are you suggesting exactly?

Comment: Thanks, can you please help me to know how to use an appender for that? I am pretty new to this stuff.

Comment: On adding those 2 lines u said, here are the errors: `log4j:ERROR Could not find value for key log4j.appender.debug.layout
log4j:WARN File option not set for appender [debug].
log4j:WARN Are you using FileAppender instead of ConsoleAppender?
log4j:ERROR Could not find value for key log4j.appender.debug.layout`

Comment: I added the file option, here are the errors: `log4j:ERROR Could not find value for key log4j.appender.debug.layout
log4j:ERROR Could not find value for key log4j.appender.debug.layout
log4j:ERROR No layout set for the appender named [debug].`

Comment: So that is telling me that the file appender you have named debug requires the properties layout and File, and they have not been set?  File refers to the location of the file to print the log to, so the value should be something like log4j.appender.debug.File=C:/Users/ConMan/Documents/logs/myLog.log and the layout refers to the layout pattern to use for the log file, e.g. log4j.appender.debug.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout, which then requires the property log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n

Comment: Sorry it took so long to get there!

Answer (score 1):

You having problem in the `rootLogger`, you should have only one logging level e.g `DEBUG, INFO, ERROR etc..` in your case you having multiple logging levels and second thing you didn't declare `file` appender in your `rootLogger` but you used it in rest of the snippets.

`# Root logger option
log4j.rootLogger=info, debug, error file`

The above snippet should be like this `log4j.rootLogger= INFO, file`

Have a look at this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27163310/tomcat-save-log-history/27167859#27167859)